# Regex to match url with or without 'folder'

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to get the right regex to match the following;

`content/foo/B6128/8918/foo+bar+foo`

OR

`content/foo/B6128/8918/foo+bar+foo/randomstringnumsletters`

I'm sure this isn't that complicated and I'm nearly there, just can't get it perfected. Here's what I've tried;

```
content\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+[\w]+)\/?(\w*)$
```

using this online tester: http://regex101.com/r/sB8rR5/2

It still matches a 5th item with this string `content/foo/B6128/8918/foo+bar+foo`;

And while technically this pattern does match either OR url structures. I don't want it to match the 5th item when there's no `randomstringnumsletters` present.

After playing around with it for a bit, I do realise some elements are redundant with what I've tried, but I'm not getting anywhere with it...

Comment: How can you tell if such a folder exists?

Comment: well that's why i put folder in italics, it's not actually a folder, it's a get variable.

Comment: Regardless, how can you tell if you should be capturing it or not? what makes `B6128` valid but `randomstringsnumsletters` not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn the last capturing group into an optional one, and change `\w*` to `\w+` in the last capturing group inorder to prevent null character to be captured by the 5th group.

```
content\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+[\w]+)\/?(\w+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB8rR5/6)

Comment: I may not have been clear enough with my question. I do want to match the 5th set if it exists. e.g. in [this example](http://regex101.com/r/sB8rR5/4) I want the first match to not return the 5th element whereas I do want it to return the 5th in the second match. Does that make sense?

Comment: oh sorry see http://regex101.com/r/sB8rR5/6 . I think this is what you want? let me know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your REAL pattern should be:

```
content\/((?:\w+\/?)+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB8rR5/2)

or am I wrong? This will match the whole string (after `content/`) and return it all `/` delimited. You can parse each variable from there.

Comment: That doesn't then split up the values between the slashes, kind of defeats the point of using regex in this case. I might as well use `content\/(.+)`

Comment: @Novocaine88 YMMV. I prefer to match all content then parse the match rather than try and create separate groups, some of which may be empty (as you're observing now)

Answer (score 0):

You can take each part as an array, then take the part that you need...

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fU1yV8/1)